# How to pass a Window as a parameter to another class in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Part 01

Instead of make an object of window then show it like this:

```
  private void prof(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     prof form = new prof();
     form.Show();
  }

  private void multi(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     multi form = new multi();
     form.Show();
  }

  private void userset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     userset form = new userset();
     form.Show();
  }

  private void sysset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     sysset form = new sysset();
     form.Show();
  }
```

I want to pass the window name to a class and that class can do the stuff

```
  public void loadWindow (ref Window x)
  {
     x form = new x();
     form.Show()
  }
```

then I want to use these syntax:

```
 loadWindow(prof);
 loadWindow(multi);
 loadWindow(userset);
```

How can I do that?
any help would be appreciated

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3232685/4448418) SO answer might useful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly then you should be able to use a generic method:

```
public void LoadWindow<TWindow>() where TWindow : Window, new()
{
    var form = new TWindow();

    form.Show();
}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
LoadWindow<Window1>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Generics,

```
 private void loadWindow<T>() where T : Window, new()
        {
            T w = new T();
            w.Show();
        }
```